# powershell filter csv

Tags: powershell, csv

Looking for help on best practice as I am Powershell newbie,

I have a csv file and I would like to filter out every row in the csv except for the rows containing "Not Installed"

I would then like to filter those results against a separate csv files housing a list of computers and also exclude any rows containing a match.

Any help or starting points would be appreciated !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the first part, you can use `Select-String -Notmatch ...` e.g.:

```
$file = "data.csv"
$csv = Get-Content $file
$csv | Select-String -Notmatch 'Not Installed' | Out-File $file -Enc ascii
```

If your CSV file happens to be Unicode, then remove the "-Enc ascii" part since the default for Out-File is Unicode.  As for the second part of your question, you're going to need to be bit more specific.  However, you should look at the help on Import-Csv and Export-Csv:

```
man Import-Csv -full
man Export-Csv -full
```

Comment: This actually works really well. I had similar commands previously but didn't specify -Enc ascii so it game me undesirable results. The second part needs to compare the new data.csv file to another csv list which has exclusions that need to be filtered out. The command above would probably work, maybe I can just get-content of the exclusions list into an array and change 'Not Installed' the $exclusions?

Comment: If you use Import-Csv to pull in both CSV files, you wind up with an array of objects where each object has properties corresponding to the fields in CSV file.  So you could do something like this `$importedCsv1 | Where {$csv1Field= $_.Field; ($importedCsv2 | Where {$_.FilterField -eq $csv1Field}).Count -eq 0 }`

Comment: $csv | Select-String -NotMatch $exclusions | Out-File $hosts -Enc ascii works to remove all exclusions from the data.csv file but it leaves a blank row at the top for every match it removes. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like PS formatting of MatchInfo object.  Try this `$csv | Select-String -NotMatch $exclusions | Foreach {$_.Line} | Out-File $hosts -enc ascii`.

Comment: Here is my finished script:

#Copies all csv's into one file
(Get-Content *.csv) | Set-Content hosts.csv

$exclusions = Get-Content "c:\Sandbox\TMVS\exclusions.csv"
$hosts = "hosts.csv"
$csv = Get-Content $hosts


#Filters csv for only computers with nothing installed
$csv | Select-String -pattern 'Not Installed' | Out-File $hosts -Enc ascii

#Filters hosts list to remove any clients listed on the exclusions list
($csv = Get-Content $hosts) | Select-String -NotMatch $exclusions | Out-File $hosts -Enc ascii

Comment: Actually that command only adds 1 line every time it is executed, in production it will only be executed once so one blank line would be acceptable. For my test I had executed it a couple times which won't be the case in production. Thanks for all your help! I'm sure you will be seeing more questions from me in the near future :)

Comment: To help get those questions answered, you should mark answers as the accepted "answer" - if you find they answer your question.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

`get-help *csv*`

`get-help import-csv -examples`

example csv file called test.txt

```
header1,header2,header3
installed,2,3
not installed,2,3
```

Import the file into a powershell variable and filter it.

```
$p = Import-CSV .\test.txt
$p | Where { $_.header1 -eq 'installed'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Came across this question when trying to work out how to do the same thing myself.

What I came up with as a solution was as follows:

```
$Filtered = $Table|Select-String -Pattern $ExcludeStrings -NotMatch -SimpleMatch
$FilteredArray = @()
$Filtered.Line | foreach {$split = $_ -split ';';
                          $tidied = $split -replace '@|{|}|^ ';
                          $obj = New-Object System.Object
                          $tidied|foreach {$obj|Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ($_.split('=')[0]) -Value ($_.split('=')[1])
                                            }
                          $FilteredArray += $obj  
                            }
```

The first line is just showing me filtering the array that I got via `Import-CSV` to get only the results I wanted.

Unfortunately, this leaves me with a MatchInfo array, with each array being in the following format:

```
@{Column1=Value1; Column2=Value2; Column3=Value3;}
```

This does not export back out to CSV nicely at all, as is.

So, I opted to create a new output array (`$FilteredArray`).

I then piped the `Line` property of the matchinfo array from `Select-String` into a foreach loop, and for each line, I split it on the semi-colon, then I remove the @{} chars and any leading spaces.

I then create a new `System.Object`, then pipe the tidied output into another foreach loop, creating new NotePropertys in the obj, naming them from the current line in the tidied output up to the = character, and the value being the remaining text after the = character.

What I end up with is:

```
PS C:\Users\Graham> $obj

Column1            : Value1
Column2            : Value2
Column3            : Value3
```

And the filtered array looks like:

```
PS C:\Users\Graham> $FilteredArray[0..3]|Format-table

Column1         Column2        Column2                                    
-------         -------        -------
Value1          Value2         Value3 
Value1          Value2         Value3
Value1          Value2         Value3
```

Comment: The solution given by @paul-rowland would have achieved this result in a simpler fashion, while using the `-notmatch` filter.  Figure out which column your text is that you want to exclude (or match) - in my sample, "OSName" is the column that contains operating system names, and I want to exclude server OSes. To produce a filtered table with the entries as PSCustomObjects ready for further processing, import the CSV, then do something like `$filtered = $csv | where { $_.OSName -notmatch 'Server'}`