# Sorting a CSV File and Filtering Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

First what I am trying to do is Filter out and delete all of the data except the administrators in the Name0 column but I want to leave everything that is in the row of them administrators.[Here is the image of how the data looks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvl9O.png)

```
Import-Csv 'U:\Local Group Members.csv' | Sort-Object -Property Name0 | Export-Csv -notypeinformation U:\newcsv.csv
```

How do I filter out everything except the administrators which is in the Name0 column?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [powershell filter csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16028787/powershell-filter-csv)

Answer (score 2):

You could filter with the `Where-Object` cmdlet

```
Import-Csv 'U:\Local Group Members.csv' |
    Where-Object {$_.Name0 -eq "administrators"} |
    Export-Csv -notypeinformation U:\newcsv.csv
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked great! What if I needed to add something in with the administrators? Would it go like this?

Comment: Import-Csv 'U:\Local Group Members.csv' |
     Where-Object {$_.Name0 -eq "administrators","Users"} |
     Export-Csv -notypeinformation U:\newcsv.csv

Comment: @user7938223 You could use the `-or` statement to add another conditional. eg. `{$_.Name0 -eq "administrators" -or $_.Name0 -eq "Users"}`. Otherwise you could use `-match` which uses regex and `|` e.g. `{$_.Name0 -match "administrators|Users"}`  Also if an answer worked for you, it's best practice to [vote on or accept it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Lastly, say I wanted to add another field with the follow.       Where-Object {$_.caption0 -eq "Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise","Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise","Microsoft Windows 7 Professional","Microsoft Windows 8 Enterprise","Microsoft Windows 8 Pro","Microsoft Windows 8.1 Enterprise","Microsoft Windows 8.1 pro"}|

Comment: I would be using the caption0 column then.

Comment: @user7938223 The principals of my previous comment would apply. `{($_.Name0 -eq "administrators" -or $_.Name0 -eq "Users") -and ($_.caption0 -match 'Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise|Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise|Microsoft Windows 7 Professional|Microsoft Windows 8 Enterprise|Microsoft Windows 8 Pro|Microsoft Windows 8.1 Enterprise|Microsoft Windows 8.1 pro')}`

Comment: <grammarian nitpick>"principles", not "principals"</grammarian nitpick>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43408185/use-array-of-strings-for-comparing-in-where-object-in-powershell

`$Admin_User_Strings = @("adm", "admin", "administrator")`  : 
`$users | Where-Object {$Admin_User_Strings -contains $_.Description}`
 or:
`$users | Where-Object $_.Description -in $Admin_User_Strings`
or:
`$users | Where-Object $_.Description -match "adm|admin|administrator"`