# Filtering Data By Property

Tags: powershell, filter

I'm seraching for a solution to filter entries in a csv in Powershell

My File looks like this

```
Header1;Header2;Header3
Tom;15;15.12.2008
Anna;17;
Tim;18;12.01.2007
```

My Code looks atm like this :

```
$altdaten = Get-Content -Path $altdatenpf | Select-Object  -skip 1 |`
            ConvertFrom-Csv  `
                -Delimiter ";"`
                -Header $categoriesCSV

$neudaten = Get-Content -Path $neudatenpf | Select-Object  -skip 1 |`
            ConvertFrom-Csv  `
                -Delimiter ";"`
                -Header $categoriesCSV








$zdaten = foreach ($user in $neudaten)
{
    Where-Object $user.Austrittsdatum -EQ ''
}

$zdaten | export-Csv -Path '.\Test\zwischendaten.csv'
```

In this case i want delete all entrys that are like tim and Tom, they have entrys in header3

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please show us your code, so we can point you in the right direction. Look at this question in StackOverflow, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16028787/powershell-filter-csv or at one of the many other blogs about this topic.

Comment: edited it in main question ty for the hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$altdaten = Get-Content -Path .\pathToCsvFile.csv | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';'

$zdaten = $altdaten | Where-Object { $_.Header3 -eq $null }
```

Your equality operator checks actually an empty string. However, in your CSV file, there is nothing. Hence, you need to check for `$null`.

Alternatively, if you are not sure, you can use:

```
$zdaten = $altdaten | Where-Object { [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Header3) }
```

This covers either option and also looks appealing (for me at least).

Comment: That helped **very** much the one liner is nice